# Datatable does not show sliced dataframe

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a callback as shown below:

```
@app.callback(Output('output-data-from-tbl', 'children'),
             [Input('tbl-to-ner', 'n_clicks')],
             [State('datatable', 'derived_virtual_data'),
              State('datatable', 'derived_virtual_selected_rows')]
              )
def save_current_table(nextbtn, rows, derived_virtual_selected_rows):

    if derived_virtual_selected_rows is None:
        derived_virtual_selected_rows = []

    global df_yake
    dff = df_yake if rows is None else pd.DataFrame(rows)

    dff = dff.iloc[derived_virtual_selected_rows]
    print(dff)
    return html.Div(
        [
            dt.DataTable(
                data=dff.to_dict('records'),
                columns=[{"name": str(i), "id": str(i), "deletable": False, "selectable": False} for i in
                         dff.columns],
                filter_action="native",
                sort_action="native",
                sort_mode="multi",
                column_selectable="single",
                selected_columns=[],
                selected_rows=[],
                # hidden_columns=['CI'],
                page_action="native",
                page_current=0,
                page_size=10,
                style_cell={'textAlign': 'left',
                            'minWidth': '360px',
                            'width': '360px',
                            'maxWidth': '360px',
                            'whiteSpace': 'normal'
                            }
            ),

        ],
        style={'height': 300,
               'width': "100%",
               'margin-top': '20',
               'font-size': '12'},
        className='eight columns'
    )
```

The code works fine and displays the entire table if I do not include this piece of code.

```
dff = dff.iloc[derived_virtual_selected_rows]
```

However, once I slice the dataframe, the datatable returns an empty table (The headers are shown but has empty data and no rows).

I am having trouble understanding why this is happening and how to work around the problem. I don't see any queries from other users so I apologise if this is a duplicate. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!